# What is this crash stack trace while running Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. It crashes with this stack trace when I try to open it. I am not sure what went wrong.

I tried running VS in safe mode, I deleted all the *.suo files, I deleted all the *.user files - they didnt help. Thanks!

```
Unexpected exception Buffer cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: buffer  
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.InvokeOnUIThread(InvokableBase invokable)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke[TResult](Func`1 method)&#x000D;&#x000A; 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.AvatarCache..ctor(AvatarSize size, Byte[] value, Boolean isGenerated, Logger logger)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ProfileCache..ctor(Profile profile, Guid serverId, Uri profileUri, String emailAddress, Logger logger)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Connector.&lt;ConnectAsync&gt;d__1.MoveNext()
  &#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  &#x000D;&#x000A;  
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A; 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.IdeUserSession.&lt;ConnectAndInitializeSessionAsync&gt;d__a.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;  
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A; 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A; 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.&lt;ConnectAsyncImpl&gt;d__17.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- 
  End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.&lt;ConnectAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.&lt;PollConnectAsync&gt;d__22.MoveNext()</description>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

me too! I became the same phenomenon 4 hours ago.
I made progress as I tried the command below.
I got to use it once I signed in again.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE> devenv.exe /ResetUserData

Comment: Every solution says that this /resetUserData command will work but for me, although it eliminates the crash, now presents me with "your 30-day trial has expired" and an option to login. Attempting to login hangs VS.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the results you tried.
Our team is Visual Studio 2013
 Update 4 was used.
And I encountered this trouble.
One of the team members said that when you applied Update 5 it recovered more completely